# type mismatch: expected &-ptr, found i32 when trying to use vector as iterator

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use the `vec!` macro to create an iterator and pass it into a function, but I'm getting a compiler error:

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec!(1,2,3).iter();
    Foo(v);
}

fn Foo<I: Iterator<Item=i32>>(i: I) {}
```

Results in:

```
error: type mismatch resolving `<std::slice::Iter<'_, _> as std::iter::Iterator>::Item == i32`:
 expected &-ptr,
    found i32 [--explain E0271]
 --> src/main.rs:3:5
3 |>     Foo(v);
  |>     ^^^
note: required by `Foo`
```

I don't understand what the compiler is trying to relay to me... What is the `.iter()` returning if it is not a `Iterator<i32>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the iterator returned by [`iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter) is an iterator over references to the vector items.

This can be seen in [the method signature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter): `fn iter(&self) -> Iter<T>` 
and the `Iterator` implementation of `Iter`, which [states](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html#associatedtype.Item):

```
impl<'a, T> Iterator for Iter<'a, T>
    type Item = &'a T
    ...
```

One possible solution is to make the `foo` function take an iterator of references:

```
fn foo<'a, I: Iterator<Item=&'a i32>>(i: I) { }
```

A somewhat better solution is to call the [`into_iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_iter) method on the vector. This takes ownership of the vector and iterates over its values, consuming each one. This will not always be what you want, however, but the compiler will warn you as it did this time around.

---

You could also declare `foo` like this:

```
fn foo<I: IntoIterator<Item=i3‌​2>>(i: I)
```

The [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) trait is implemented for types that can be converted to iterators via `into_iter`. This way you would call the function with the vector and convert it in the function body.